# Revoke permission of system apps without root

Tags: adb, permissions

I was wondering if there is any way I could revoke permission of a system app without having root. And if the is a way and I managed to do it are there any side effects that might result in the app crashing or not opening at all. The permission I want to revoke is HIDE_NON_SYSTEM_OVERLAY_WINDOWS.
And the apps are Package Installer and Permission Controller.
Thank you